# When opening "layout_main.xml" Android Studio says "Rendering Error"

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I downloaded the Android Studio from the official android developers website. It was < 887 MB. After the download I installed the Studio. And launched the Android Studio Successfully. After the program is started the program says **"Indexing...."** for about 2 minutes. While it was saying "Indexing" I opened the file **"layout_main.xml"**. The application failed to show me the layout. But the Toolbox is loaded. **"Initializing"** for 1 minute and Shows an error. Please answer me sir. Please.

Comment: Try to change theme from top bar option menu.

Answer (score 0):

set your Rendering Api level to 21. it solve your max problem

[image]